# Reduction of basis and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S$ is a $5-$dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^6$ .Is it true that every basis of $\mathbb{R}^6$ can be reduced to a basis of $S$ by removing one vector ?

Comment: So do you think it is true or false? If not sure, try looking at a simpler example, eg 2D subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Every basis is linearly  independent so it can be reduced to an echelon from and by removing one vector the echelon from should remain the same ie linearly independent  so I think it should be true ..

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}^3$. Removing one of the standard basis vectors from the standard basis gives you only three possible planes. But there are infinitely many possible planes through the origin.

Comment: Through origin but basis do not include zero vectors

Comment: All subspaces of a vector space include the origin!

Comment: yes but basis don't otherwise it won't remain a basis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing a vector from a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ you always have a basis of some subspace $S$ of dimension $n-1$. This is true because you have $n-1$ linearly independent vectors that spans a subspace.  But If you want a **particular** subspace $S$ then the statement is not true in general and you have to find  $n-1$ linearly independent vectors that span this space, and these vectors can be a linear combinations of the starting basis vectors.

As  an example, if $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$ are the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ than the subspace $S$ spanned by $(1,3)$ ( the line of points $(x,3x)^T$ that has dimension $1$) has a basis vector that is not $(1,0)^T$ nor $(0,1)^T$

Comment: Can I know where is my mistake?

Comment: And (1,3)=1 (1,0)+3 (0,1)

Comment: @RipanJeet So, which one of $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ can you remove and still be able to form $(1,3)$ with the one remaining vector?

Comment: The point is that we cannot obtain a basis for $Span (1,3)^T$ removing one vector from the basis $(1,0)^T,(0,1)^T$, but this is possibile removing avector from anothr basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as, foe example $(1,3)^T,(3,1)^T$. And the vecortors of this basis are obviously linear combinations of th first basis.

Comment: Means from Some basis of R^2  we can make Some basis of R not Every

Comment: No! From a basis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can extract a basis of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that has dimension$1$, so this subspace is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, but it does not coincide with $\mathbb{R}$, and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have infinitely many subspace isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Similarly from a basis of R^6 we can extract a basis of a subspace of R^6 that has dimension 5 ..

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simple example and build on it.

Consider the basis of $\mathbb R^6$ : $span[(1,0,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,0,0,1)] $

It's clear that if you remove the vector $(0,0,0,0,0,1)$, then none of the other vectors generate a $6th$ dimension, so yes, indeed, removing that vector, you get the standard basis of $\mathbb R^5$. Now, for a more general example, for a particular subspace $S$, in order to take a basis for the $S^{n-1}$ space, from a set of vectors, for example, $span[v_1,v_2,..,v_n$], you will need to find $n-1$ in number linear independent vectors that create the $n-1$ dimension space, from the $n$ dimension space you already have.

Comment: Not span but basis every vector is L.I. so by removing one they should still be L.I. and spanning. . So they should from a basis ..

Comment: It's the same, vectors that form the span or otherwise written as $<(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)>$

Comment: That means the statement is true..

Comment: One thing more .. like i remove (1,0,0) from basis of R^3 remaining vectors are (0,1,0) , (0,0,1) .. how can these make a basis of R^2 ?? Basis of R^2 are of the type ( x , y )  ..

Comment: Your comments are not making sense. Read the text, understand what it says. Look at the example. You remove the n-th dimension generating. Please, read more carefully before you spam comments.

Comment: Sorry if it felt rude i didnt mean to spam Charalampos Filippatos